# Nested CSS Tabs, Conflicting ul and li formatting

Tags: css, html

I have a tab system built in css using unordered lists and list items.  I would like to embed a second tab structure using the same visual style within my content region.  I was able to do that and everything functioned, but there is an appearance issue.  Within my content region I have a different set up ul definitions.  I would essentially like to tell one div to follow half of the instructions defined in the content region.  The spacing and that type of formatting is needed, but I would like the ul stuff ignored.

If anyone has experience in this, I will gladly supply any needed code.  I didn't want to post a bunch of stuff that didn't assist in solving the problem though.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I believe you will have to create another set of rules with their selectors prefixed with `#contentregion` or something

Answer (score 0):

Apply an "un-reset" CSS block to your content region.

See: https://github.com/jbcrawford/Un-ResetStylesheet

or: http://noscope.com/vanilla-css

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically target the lis and uls only in your content and override values you dont want or change.

If your content is in a wrapper called #content, and the tabs are called .tabs then do

```
#content .tabs {
background-image:none;
margin:0px;
}
```

and so on, setting the values you need.

How are the tabs styled? Use the exact same selectors but put a selector in front of them, like the content wrapper so you can target them specifically.

Hard to give you an exact answer without any code.